# How to handle dynamic xpath for newly generated data?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, pycharm

I am working on automating a webpage using PyCharm and Selenium(Python), in which i am creating a data and after creating it, **i want to edit/update/delete the data**. In my case, the xpath of edit element is `rel xpath= //tr[{Digits}]//td[4]//a[1]` in which the `{Digits}` i.e. the row id value keeps on changing, it may increase or decrease according to business requirement. Same goes with delete element `rel xpath= //tr[{Digits}]//td[5]//a[1]`.

What i am trying to achieve is, i want to click the edit and delete elements which is only achievable using the xpaths mentioned above(in which the table row ids are dynamically changing).
Apart from these two elements no other elements are clickable or could make any changes in the record/data which i have created. So is it possible to handle dynamic row ids of the table for the list of the records/data created?
Since i am not allowed to share picture but i could share the following details:

Attributes which i got for Edit element are:

```
<a class="coral-Link coral-Link--subtle" href="/lucent/service_detail_types/292/edit" style=""><i class="coral-Icon coral-Icon--sizeXS coral-Icon--edit"></i></a>
```

Attributes which i got for Delete element are:

```
<a class="coral-Link coral-Link--subtle coral-Form-fielderror" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this?" data-method="delete" href="/lucent/service_detail_types/292" rel="nofollow" xpath="1"><i class="coral-Icon coral-Icon--sizeXS coral-Icon--delete"></i></a>
```

Comment: ...you did not ask a question.

Comment: My concern is to fetch the "{Digits}" value, whenever i am creating a new data in the table.

Comment: What if you do `//tr//td[4]//a[1]`? You will get a list of *all* such `<a>` elements and can freely pick one, e.g. the last one.

Comment: No, it is not picking any value or element. My test will skip that command line and move to next one throwing error saying "No such xpath found"

Comment: That's hard to tell without more context. Maybe your XPath is simply wrong. Could also be that those elements are created by Javascript at some point after the page load and you are not waiting long enough.

Comment: Just need some idea regarding how to handle the row ids of the table. If that particular ids could be fetched than my problem would be solved.

Comment: why your are not using css selector? and you are not telling your objective? are you want to click on button?

Comment: My objective is mentioned in the topic itself. Apart from that i have highlighted as well as i have modified my question too. Regarding CSS Selector, since the table row id keeps on changing, the css values is also not able to capture the exact element which i want to be clicked.